# Powershell command using list as variable

Tags: list, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a script to look at users and what AD groups they are part of, looking for a specific group that has multiple "sub groups".
example VPN-GRP-ONE, VPN-GRP-TWO, VPN-GRP-THREE....

tried using some stuff I found on a few demos but its not working right as it wants the ActiveDirectory module imported to use get-aduser and we are not allowed to install new modules we dont already have. (I dont have ActiveDirectory in  my available modules)

I was trying to use:

```
$list1 = C:\Users\MrAoxx\Documents\List1.txt
foreach ($_ in $list1) {
net user $_ /domain}
```

I was hoping for ouput that I could then take the next step to piping that to a new text file and begin stripping what I needed out of it to get just the AD group names I was looking for ie: ONE, TWO, THREE. But all its doing is opening the txt file and nothing else.

Comment: I highly recommend you install [RSAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems) for your OS and leverage the ActiveDirectory module that is installed with it. This is a pretty standard toolset for any Windows admin, especially for an AD role.

Comment: we are not allowed to install things that are not vetted by the company INFOSEC group and that leaves us very limited.

Comment: RSAT is about as standard as a tool gets for system administration work. This isn't some third party tool, this is a standard system administration toolkit provided by Microsoft. I would be very surprised if you requested to have it installed as a Windows syadmin and get denied because "Infosec" hasn't vetted the tool.

Comment: `$list1 = Get-Content 'C:\Users\MrAoxx\Documents\List1.txt'`

Comment: The problem with using the `net user $_ /domain` that command is it truncates group names in the Group Membership sections. Unfortunately it's 2019 and I'm more skilled with the cmdlets than the `net user` command for introspecting AD, and don't know if there's some commnand that won't truncate the group membership.

Comment: I am using net user to inspect them right now and its displaying the full AD group name, but the list has hundreds of users so a script would be better.

Comment: @LotPings this did work, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$list1 = get-content 'C:\Users\MrAoxx\Documents\List1.txt'
foreach ($_ in $list1) {
net user $_ /domain >> C:\Users\MrAoxx\Documents\FullList.txt}
```

This worked the way I needed it to, thanks to @LotPings for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't fun but here you go - note that it is absolutely possible that long enough group names will get truncated:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\MrAoxx\Documents\List1.txt | Foreach-Object {
  $partOfGroups = ( ( net user $_ /domain | select-string '\*' | out-string ).Trim() -split "`r`n" ) |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(29).Trim() -split '\*' } |
    Where-Object { -Not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }

  # You can look for specific groups in $partOfGroups if that user is part
  # of any particular group, and process for that user here.
}
```

I'll step you through how this works:

1. Get the `net user` output for the current user read from the file
2. Select all lines that contain a * and convert the output to a string, trimming leading and trailing spaces.
3. Re-split the output back into an array per line for ease of processing.
4. For each line of output, remove the first 29 characters and split the rest of the text by the `*` character.
5. Remove any empty strings from the final array output

This fancypants parsing is why you should opt for [installing RSAT tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/remote-server-administration-tools). Here's how you would do it with `Get-ADUser`:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\MrAoxx\Documents\List1.txt | Foreach-Object {
  $groups = ( ( Get-ADUser $_ -Property MemberOf ).MemberOf | Get-AdGroup ).Name

  # Process here
}
```

Comment: This also worked and removed the non AD group info for me, thanks.

Comment: Where do you find RSAT tools to install?

Comment: @not2qubit I've added a link in the answer to Microsoft's instructions on how to install it

Answer (score 2):

I see you have accepted an answer already, yet, here are other approaches to maybe ease this kind of effort for you. So, as for this ...

> --- '(I dont have ActiveDirectory in my available modules)' ---
>
> --- we are not allowed to install things ---

... and do you even need to actually install / enable them on your system to use them. This is what Implicit PSRemoting is for, and or using the built-in .Net namespace or adsisearcher.

***How to us either of them:***

[Use PowerShell Active Directory Cmdlets Without Installing Any Software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-active-directory-cmdlets-without-installing-any-software/)

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName dc1 –credential nwtraders\administrator
Set-Location c:\
Import-Module activedirectory
```

[Powershell Remote Use of Module Commandlets (Remoting Import-Module)](https://adsecurity.org/?p=303)

```
# Create a Powershell remote session to a server with the #commandlets installed.
$Session = New-PSsession -Computername Server1

# Use the newly created remote Powershell session to send a #command to that session
Invoke-Command -Command {Import-Module ActiveDirectory} -Session $Session

# Use that session with the modules to add the available 
# commandlets to your existing Powershell command shell with a 
# new command name prefix.
Import-PSSession -Session $Session -Module ActiveDirectory -Prefix RM
```

[Working with Active Directory using PowerShell ADSI adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx)

```
# Searching for an object
$Searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
$Searcher.Filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(anr=gusev))'
$Searcher.SearchRoot = 'LDAP://OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=com'
$Searcher.FindAll()
```

Comment: the import function requires privs that we dont have, and getting the exception for my credentials requires putting in a request and explaining why this is an absolute need rather than something that can assist.